# Grails 2.0: POST and flash.message

Tags: unit-testing, grails, post, grails-2.0

Having the following in your controller:

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
```

will cause the `save()` action for example to set an empty `flash` map. I.e. the following test will fail because flash is `[:]` after the action returns and message is `null`:

Controller:

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
[...]
def save = {
    flash.message = "Saved"
}
```

Test:

```
void testSave() {
    controller.save()
    assert null != flash.message
}
```

**Is there any reason for that or is that a bug in Grails 2.0?**

Comment: For now I am checking the method in the controller actions programatically as described here:
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html
But this can't be the solution can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason flash is empty is that you have defined save() to use only POST method. That's what grails do - it doesn't allow you to access save() with GET. Your complete test should look like this:

```
void testSaveWithGet() {
    controller.save()
    assert response.status == HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
} 

void testSaveWithPost() {
    request.method = "POST"
    controller.save()
    assert flash.message == "Saved"
}
```